# jquery validation shows uncaught type error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, materialize

Trying to implement jquery validation because I need to be able to validate hidden inputs.

I initialize the plugin in document ready but on submit, I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at a.validator.elementValue (jquery.validate.min.js:4:10471)
    at a.validator.check (jquery.validate.min.js:4:11074)
    at a.validator.checkForm (jquery.validate.min.js:4:7116)
    at a.validator.form (jquery.validate.min.js:4:6816)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.min.js:4:1146)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (vendors.min.js:1:391918)
    at HTMLFormElement.f.handle (vendors.min.js:1:389932)
```

I'm using Materializecss and laravel 8, if its relevant. The form is in a modal that is triggered on click but for the sake of testing, I'm always showing it right now. Here is the way I initialize the plugin:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bookingForm").validate();
    });
```

And here is the form:

```
         <form class="col s12 m12 l12" id="bookingForm" role="form">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">
                <h4>{{ $post->name }}</h4>
                <h6 class="" style="font-size: 14px;margin-top: 0px;">{{ $post->organizer->name }}</h6> 
                <div class="row center"> 
                    <div class="row center">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l4">
                            <select id="city_ids" name="city_ids" class="browser-default">
                                <option value="">Plats</option>
                                @foreach($post->cities as $city)
                                    <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}, {{ $city->county->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach                                
                            </select>
                        </div>             
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2">
                            <select id="time_ids" name="time_ids" class="browser-default">
                                <option value="">Tillfälle</option>
                                @foreach($post->bookingTimes as $bookingTime)
                                    <option value="{{ $bookingTime->id }}">{{ $bookingTime->bookingDateTime }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m6 l1 offset-l5 pb-1">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <span>Boka för Företag</span>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="studiecentralen-pink-title-NU">Fyll i deltagarens uppgifter</h5>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Namn" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Gatuadress" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="address" name="address" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  C/O" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="careoff" name="careoff" type="text" class="search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Postnummer" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="zip" name="zip" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Ort" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="city" name="city" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Epost" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="email" name="email" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <input placeholder="  Telefonnummer" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-error=".errorTxt3" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="validate search-term main-search studiecentralen-bg" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>               
                    <div class="extraParticipants"></div>
                    <div class="row center">
                        <div class="col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <p id="noMore" style="display:none;">Vill du lägga in fler deltagare kan du göra en till bokning eller skriva i meddelandefältet.</p>
                            <button id="addParticipant" type="button" style="border-radius: 50px;height:30px;padding: 1px 10px;display: inline-flex;align-items: center;" class="modal-action btn buttonShadow center">Lägg till en deltagare</button>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5">
                            <textarea id="inquiry" name="inquiry" class="studiecentralen-textarea studiecentralen-bg materialize-textarea validate" placeholder="   Har du något att tillägga?"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m6 l2 offset-l5 pb-1">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" required/>
                            <span>Jag samtycker till att studiecentralen sparar min information och förmedlar informationen till arrangör av bokad utbildning</span>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row center"> 
                    <button type="submit" style="border-radius: 50px;height:30px;padding: 1px 10px;display: inline-flex;align-items: center;" class="modal-action btn buttonShadow center">Skicka</button>
                </div>         
                </div> 
            </div>           
        </form>
```

Comment: try adding `console.log($("#bookingForm"))` and copy the results from console

Comment: Of course it was very simple... The issue was that the checkboxes were missing the name attribute

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue was that the checkboxes didn't have a name attribute..

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are trying get `#bookingForm` before its created.
move you script tag to bottom of your HTML page and its gonna work properly.

Comment: The form is created normally, without jquery, using ordinary html. The initialization of the plugin is on document ready and is at the very bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is late for you, but maybe it can help others. I encountered the same problem and removing the "required" attribute solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox don't have a name. Add name property. It will validate

Comment: Hello, try to add some code snippet or some example for more readability.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).